# Why don't my logs print?

Tags: android, logging, logcat

```
Log.i("CONNECT TO THE NETZ!","BOOM");
```

Prints nothing in LogCat. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you running logcat? Try `adb logcat V` in a shell to make sure you get every message without any filters.

Comment: im running in eclipse, using adt plugin

Comment: looks like the logs appear in my shell, but how can I print results to the console as my program is running?

Comment: Also, logcat in Eclipse has filters (look for those cool buttons with V/D/I/E). If you set those filters up right, you can use logcat in Eclipse as well and don't have to use a shell. But typing `adb logcat V` in the shell is a good way to quickly see everything, without having to worry about your filters not being set up right.